# Which language to choose? #suggestions

Tags: api, cassandra, cloud

I know this question might have been asked many times but I could not found any suggestions that might help me. What I have is a tool written in php and a service written in java. I will be moving the service part into cloud based architecture, So currently I have to make a API for database which I want should be independent module from service and the tool. So my question is which language to choose to write this database API php or java. This database api in future we plan to move to apache cassandra. Suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Right now the DataStax Java driver [1](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) is more up to date than its younger brother the DataStax PHP driver [2](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) (though the latter will catch up soon).

Comment: I won't be using DataStax Cassandra . I will be using version provided by Apache. Will DataStax be more helpful?